# SQL Count all null values as distinct

Tags: sql

I need to write a query that tells me how many(COUNT) unique customers made a purchase of over $200. My table has a customer_id, purchase_id, and total. purchase_id is unique for every row. Customer_id can repeat, and also have null values.

A "unique customer is considered a unique customer_id or a null customer_id. So in the list:

```
1
2
1
null
null
null
```

There would be 5 unique customers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Either show the work you have attempted or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT (
(SELECT COUNT DISTINCT customer_id FROM TABLE where total > 200 and customer_id IS NOT NULL) +
(SELECT COUNT customer_id FROM TABLE where total > 200 and customer_id IS NULL)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL should give you the result

```
select (select count(distinct customer_id)) + 
       (select count(*) from a where customer_id is null)
  from your table
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
select
  count(distinct customer_id) + 
  count(case when customer_id is null then 1 end) as counter
from tablename 
where total > 200
```

The 1st count() will count all distinct non null customer_ids and the 2nd will count the nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You need can do your filter inner query and use `union all`. `Distinct` will only fetch once when customer id is not null. On the other hand you are counting every null value as separate customer. Below query will help you.

```
select count(*) from (
   select distinct customerid 
    from table_name 
   where customerid is not null 
         and total > 200 
    union all 
   select customerid 
    from table name 
    where customerid is null 
      and total>200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple SQL.

```
SELECT customer_id, count(*) AS count
FROM t1
WHERE total > 200
GROUP BY customer_id
```

or to get a simple count of unique customers...

```
SELECT count(*) AS totalUniqueCustomers
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM t1
  WHERE total > 200
  GROUP BY customer_id
) s1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c4a8/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (purchase_id int IDENTITY, customer_id int, total int);

INSERT INTO t1 (customer_id, total)
VALUES 
      (1, 202)
    , (2, 250)
    , (1, 10)
    , (null, 1000)
    , (null, 20)
    , (null, 500)
    , (3, 10)
;
/* NOTE: I added orders with both over and under the 200 mark to show excluding 
   the ones you don't want. */
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT customer_id, count(*) AS count
FROM t1
WHERE total > 200
GROUP BY customer_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c4a8/4/0)**:

```
| customer_id | count |
|-------------|-------|
|      (null) |     2 |
|           1 |     1 |
|           2 |     1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
/* TO GET A SIMPLE COUNT OF UNIQUE CUSTOMERS */
SELECT count(*) AS totalUniqueCustomers
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM t1
  WHERE total > 200
  GROUP BY customer_id
) s1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c4a8/4/1)**:

```
| totalUniqueCustomers |
|----------------------|
|                    3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
select count(distinct customer_id) + sum(case when customer_id is null then 1 else 0 end)
from t;
```

The `count(distinct)` counts the number of distinct non-`NULL` values.  The second adds in the number of `NULL`s.

In some databases you can simplify the second expression.  For example, in MySQL:

```
select count(distinct customer_id) + sum( customer_id is null )
from t;
```